# Replic-Action log error Cannot open Link: TNS Could not resolve the service name

Tags: oracle10g, replication, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Hi I am working with ReplicAction tool to transfer data from Lotus Notes View to Oracle Database.

When i Create the link document for Oracle DB it is created successfully without any error
When I create the Include Table for Oracle Db it is created successfully and all columns are listed

When i create the Replication it is also created successfully,

But when the job executes it gives the error is log :

```
05/08/2012 01:37:16 AM   Starting Replication: BADtoProductPortal 
05/08/2012 01:37:19 AM   Error: <ODBC Error> [DataDirect][ODBC Oracle driver][Oracle]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name

05/08/2012 01:37:19 AM   Error: Information: Unable to open Link: PPLink
05/08/2012 01:37:19 AM   Error: Replication to Link <PPLink> did not complete
05/08/2012 01:37:20 AM   End of Replication: BADtoProductPortal
```

If the error is with service name, Then i think we should not be able to create Link document also.

When i use ODBC connection for link, then i am unable to create Replication job, giving the error like Notes Data field "ID" does not match the source data field.

But i know it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check that the TASK runing the job uses the same TNS entry as you are doing "manually".
I suggest to check that the TASK has also access to your Oracle driver. This tasks has right to run it?

ORA-12154 error is thrown during the logon process to a database. This error indicates that the communication software (TNS) in Oracle ( SQL *Net or Net8 ) did not recognize the host/service name specified in the connection parameters.

So the issue is clearly a type en "environment difference" between your configuration when you run manually the replication and when the job run it.
Hope I help

Comment: The issue is not with the service name. As all is unchanged since it was last working. The job stopped working all of a sudden. I made sure that tns entry and service name are correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that when you successfully replicate you're doing it manually from your local machine, and when the job fails it's running scheduled on a server. If that's the case I agree with Emmanuel. Remember running the job locally uses the local tnsnames.ora file, running it scheduled uses the tnsnames.ora file on the server. You may not be aware of anything changing but are you responsible for maintainance on the server?

Comment: No Its not. In both the cases I have done it on server. To cut a long story short. If i create a link document to Oracle DB it is not working but when i create ODBC connecction it is working fine